# UISlider - Add UILabel to min/max UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uislider

As shown below, 
`UISlider` has a Minimum Image and Maximum Image.

These imageView elements can be set to any UIImage.

I have a custom UISlider scenario and I'm trying to simply make the left and right image a string (`UILabel`).

Any smart ideas about how I might inject a UILabel into these elements?
Or failing that, how I can extend my UISlider subclass so that it has a UILabel either side of it?

I guess I could encapsulate inside another `UIView` but I don't love that idea.

Thanks

WS

[image: UISlider layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is smart & simple idea to achieve, that you want.

Look at this snapshot:

- Do not set min and max image for UISlider.
- Set UILabels on left and right of UISlider. UILabels allows to set string value.
- You can create custom view or IBDesignable with slider & two labels. This would be very easier than subclass UISlider and overriding of default properties.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, indeed I was hoping to achieve the above *without* Interface Builder/Storyboards and also encapsulated inside the UISlider subclass I've created. I guess I could add labels in that subclass during init that offset themselves from the frame. A bit ugly though.

Comment: Nice, idea you are trying for! :)